# I have joined two tables, how to count total rows?

Tags: mysql

Example :

I have following select query which joins multiple tables,

```
SELECT
  col1.id OBJECTID,
  def.name TYPE,
  pm.partn NODENUMBER,
  pm.name NODENAME, 
  org.name ORGNAME,
  string.value CONTEXT
FROM
  PART col1, PARTMASTER pm, TYPEDEFINITION def, ORGA org, 
  STRINGVALUE string, STRINGDEFINITION def2, partmaster pmpf, part ppf
```

as a result multiple records are selected, I need to get the count of those. How can I get it ?

Comment: Try to avoid column names and aliases such as "TYPE", "STRING" and "VALUE", as they are reserved keywords in MySQL. Most of the time you can get away with it, but in some rare instances you may run into seemingly weird problems. See a list of all reserved keywords here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/keywords.html.

Answer (score 0):

is your database mysql? try this:

`SELECT count(1), col1.id OBJECTID, def.name TYPE, pm.partn NODENUMBER, pm.name NODENAME, org.name ORGNAME, string.value CONTEXT FROM PART col1, PARTMASTER pm, TYPEDEFINITION def, ORGA org, STRINGVALUE string, STRINGDEFINITION def2, partmaster pmpf, part ppf`

just add `count(1)` into your sql statement.

Comment: it seems like available in oracle too, isn't it?

Comment: which version do you have? in 10g you can find something useful [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm)